# How to write JEST test cases for the callback API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I have created a API service factory, passing dynamically URL, function as a parameter. Once it success data comes in the callback function and its working fine as per expected. For same I am going to write JEST test cases. **I couldn't fine the right approach to do it**. Can help someone. Great appreciate.

Code is here

```
function userLogin(username, password) {
  const reqBody = {
    companyEmailAddress: username,
    password,
  };
  const url = `${config.apiBaseUrl}${serviceMethodConstants.login}`;
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(serviceFactory.postData(url, false, reqBody, function (response, dispatch) {
      if (response !== undefined) {
        console.log(response )
      }
    }));
  };
}
```

**For same I wrote JEST test case, but it is not showing any error or success message as expected.**

JEST test code

```
import { userConstants } from './constants';
import { serviceFactory } from '../../services/_helpers/serviceFactory';

const loginData = {
  companyEmailAddress: 'rameshffdfdf.lambanihghgh@gmail.com',
  password: 'Ramesh@1',
};

axiosMock.onPost(routeUrl).reply(200, JSON.stringify(loginData));
const spy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post');
await store.dispatch(userActions.userLogin(...loginData, function (response, dispatch) {
    expect(response.message).toEqual('Failure');
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
}));
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`userLogin` action creator (a thunk) doesn't accept a callback and doesn't do a request. It's unknown whether `store.dispatch` returns a promise that could be awaited.

A proper strategy for unit testing is to mock everything but tested unit. Since `serviceFactory` abstraction is in use, Axios shouldn't be involved. Action creator can be tested without Redux involved, either.

```
const dispatch = jest.fn();
const postDataResult = {};
jest.spyOn(serviceFactory, 'postData').mockReturnValue(postDataResult);

userActions.userLogin('user', 'pass')(dispatch);

expect(serviceFactory.postData).toBeCalledWith(url, false, {...}, expect.any(Function));
expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith(postDataResult);
```

The test can stay synchronous this way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I made as you mentioned. I am getting an error args passing. Can you check and help me, for more reference attached screenshots within.

Comment: `logn` is wrong function, because a callback postData is called with is anonymous. You should assert the argument to be `expect.any(Function)`, not `logn`. Another problem is `...loginData`. I didn't take into account what it is in your case, but of course, a spread won't work - it's not an array.

Comment: Now, without error working fine. Is there way to check success and failure API class with response or failure objects?

Comment: What do you mean? And what does 'API class' refer to?

Comment: API(application program interface) web service call, want to show in JEST test cases, web service call done proper or not with the success and failure scenario.

Comment: This shouldn't be done in userLogin unit test. You need to test serviceFactory.postData directly in another test, that's where mockAxios may be useful.

Comment: Okay sure, I will try and get back to you. Thank you